# Deploy React App on CDN, API Backend on Server?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, cdn, serverless, cloudflare

Is there any non-trival benefits to hosting a SPA app (i.e. React) on the edge using a CDN provider like CloudFlare, but serve the API backend used by the SPA app on a regular VPS/dedicated server?

The more common approach seems to be hosting the SPA on the CDN and have a serverless backend like AWS Lambda or Cloudflare Workers. Both my app and backend are currently being served on a VPS like DigitalOcean in the US datacenter, but analytics show that my users are also coming from the other half of the globe.

Is it worth moving the React app from the VPS server to the CDN?

Thank you